# Page flickering asp net issue in chrome and firefox browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am facing page flickering issue in chrome and firefox browser. I am using asp.net Gridview control for row level price, qty calculation. Here whenever I enter some value into Qty and price textbox through gridview `onRowCreated` event, I am calculating total price in code behind.

The main problem in this system is whenever I enter some value into `Qty` or `price` textbox, the entire page is flickering (jumping). This problem occurs only in Chrome and Firefox, not in IE.

Same way when I add new row dynamically through button click event. Even I put this entire gridview control into `UpdatePanel`. But its not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility i think

In chrome and firefox when the page height is less you do not see the right hand side scroll bar. Only when the page height increases the scroll bar appears and it feels as if the page is jumping. But in internet explorer the right hand side scroll bar is always present. Its disabled when the content is less and appears active when the content in the page increases. This way you do not see the page jumping.

If this is what is happening in your case also then I feel that its normal behavior of these browsers and you should not worry much about them. Or else give a minimum height to your page so that the scroll bar is always present and you will not feel that the page is jumping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi..Yes my page height is more then web browser.But in my case if i enter value into some other field like description... this flickering not happening.Only this happening in calculative field like Qty and Price..

Comment: You will have to provide some screenshots I feel to help understand your problem !